# Find element in object array by particular order

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, javascript-objects

How can I find the object array element by particular weight order?

The current weight is `admin>acc_holder>manager`. If the role array has role `admin`, it will return the `roleId`, if not, it will find role `acc_holder`, then `manager` is the last. I have write the code on the bottom, but it's ugly and like the callback hell.

Role object array:

```
[
    {
        role: "manager",
        roleId: 2,
    },
    {
        role: "admin",
        roleId: 4,
    },
    {
        role: "acc_holder",
        roleId: 3,
    },
]
```

code:

```
const roleAdmin = roleArr.find((role) => {
    if (role.role === process.env.ROLE_ADMIN) {
        roleReturn = {
            role: role.role,
            roleId: role.roleId,
        }
    }
})
if (!roleAdmin) {
    const roleAccHolder = roleArr.find((role) => {
        if (role.role === process.env.ROLE_ACC_HOLDER) {
            roleReturn = {
                role: role.role,
                roleId: role.roleId,
            }
        }
    })
    if (!roleAccHolder) {
        const roleManager = roleArr.find((role) => {
            if (role.role === process.env.ROLE_MANAGER) {
                roleReturn = {
                    role: role.role,
                    roleId: role.roleId,
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone help me improve the function?

Answer (score 1):

I have explained two approaches below.

But there is a small thing for you to need to keep in mind

> will the `role_array` always contains the unique role record or can there be multiple records present with the same role? If that's the case, what is the behavior you want? Do you want to fetch the first of them or the last of them.?

---

**Approach 1 (maintain the highest role while looping)** simply loop over the records once and maintain the highest role present. In this approach, you will always get the last if multiple records with the same role present. The order of time complexity, in this case, will be `O(n)`

```js
// global variable
// ROLE_WEIGHTS = {[process.env.ROLE_ADMIN]: 1, [process.env.ROLE_MANAGER]: 2, [process.env.ROLE_ACC_HOLDER]: 3};
ROLE_WEIGHTS = {'admin': 1, 'acc_holder': 2, 'manager': 3};

// main method
function getHighestRole(role_array = []) {
    let highest_role = role_array[0];
    role_array.forEach((record) => {
        if (ROLE_WEIGHTS[highest_role.role] > ROLE_WEIGHTS[record.role]) {
            highest_role = record
        }
    })
    return highest_role;
}

role_array = [ { role: "manager", roleId: 2 }, { role: "admin", roleId: 4 }, { role: "acc_holder", roleId: 3 } ];
console.log(getHighestRole(role_array));

role_array = [ { role: "manager", roleId: 2 }, { role: "acc_holder", roleId: 3 } ];
console.log(getHighestRole(role_array));
```

---

**Approach 2 (sort and take first)** Sort the role array according to the weight of roles and fetch the first element. In this approach, you will always get the first if multiple records with the same role present. The order of time complexity, in this case, will be of sorting algorithms.

```js
// global variable
// ROLE_WEIGHTS = {[process.env.ROLE_ADMIN]: 1, [process.env.ROLE_MANAGER]: 2, [process.env.ROLE_ACC_HOLDER]: 3};
ROLE_WEIGHTS = {'admin': 1, 'acc_holder': 2, 'manager': 3};

// main method
function getHighestRole(role_array = []) {
    return role_array.sort((a, b) => (ROLE_WEIGHTS[a.role] - ROLE_WEIGHTS[b.role]))[0];
}

role_array = [ { role: "manager", roleId: 2 }, { role: "admin", roleId: 4 }, { role: "acc_holder", roleId: 3 } ];
console.log(getHighestRole(role_array));

role_array = [ { role: "manager", roleId: 2 }, { role: "acc_holder", roleId: 3 } ];
console.log(getHighestRole(role_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const roleArr = [{
    role: "manager",
    roleId: 2,
  },
  {
    role: "admin",
    roleId: 4,
  },
  {
    role: "acc_holder",
    roleId: 3,
  },
]

// const roleOrders = [process.env.ROLE_ADMIN, process.env.ROLE_ACC_HOLDER, process.env.ROLE_MANAGER];
const roleOrders = ['admin', 'acc_holder', 'manager'];
const selectedRole = roleOrders.reduce((result, findRole) => {
  return result || roleArr.find(({
    role
  }) => role === findRole)
}, null);

console.log(selectedRole);
```

You define the role orders, and find the array member that matches the value and skip the process when it has already found the result.